# Applying lemma to solve goal

Tags: isabelle

I am trying to prove the following lemma using the theorem

```
lemma lm22:
fixes f :: "real ⇒ 'a::banach"
assumes "a ≤ b"
and "∀x∈{a .. b}. (f has_vector_derivative f' x) (at x within {a .. b}
shows "(f' has_integral (f b - f a)) {a .. b}"
```

Isabelle output states that the goal can be solved directly with Integration.fundamental_theorem_of_calculus. However adding:

```
using fundamental_theorem_of_calculus [of a b f f'] by auto
```

does not work. I have tried defining a and b, and also replacing the variables by values but no success.

How can I apply the lemma to prove the goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isabelle's solve-direct feature considers the assumptions from the `assumes` clauses, but such assumptions are not available to proof methods like `by auto` unless you explicitly chain them in. Write `using assms` before the rest of your proof, and it should go through.